# Upload image to GraphQL server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

I'm using [react-dropzone](https://github.com/okonet/react-dropzone) and [graphql-server-express-upload](https://github.com/HriBB/graphql-server-express-upload) to upload an image all in GraphQL Apollo. In my client the file looks like this: [image: File on client]

But in the server, when I log it, it looks like this:

```
{ preview: 'blob:http://localhost:3000/c622b0bd-3f0d-4f52-91f4-7676c8534c59' }
```

I'm following the instructions in the readme in [graphql-server-express-upload](https://github.com/HriBB/graphql-server-express-upload), but no luck so far. How do I get the full image?

Comment: why don't you use a static rest route for upload, and catch the response`filepath` of that rest route and update in the db with the response of filepath and fetch the image from path while the user queries

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up using [apollo-upload-client](https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-client), works great!

Comment: Could you add your code or github link? It would be much appreciated! there is little code out there I'm finding. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

A different approach is to convert the binary image to BASE64 on the client side, before upload, then just populate the image as the BASE64 string on a GraphQLInputObjectType passed as an argument of a mutation. On the server the field can then simply be saved in a database column. For instance:

```
const UserInputType = new GraphQLInputObjectType({
  name: 'UserInput',
  description: 'The user of our system',

  fields: () => ({
    username: {
        type: GraphQLString,
        description: 'Name of the user'
    },
    image: {
        type: GraphQLString,
        description: 'Image of the user'
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: Converting to Base64 is workable for smaller files. Base64 takes up more space than the original binary, so large files create an even larger payload. Also, don't store images in the DB. It bogs down the DB and clients can't use that data directly. Store images in a storage service such as S3.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using [apollo-upload-client](https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-client).

```
const UPLOAD_IMAGE = gql`
    mutation ($input: SetUploadImage!) {
        uploadImage(input: $input) {
            clientMutationId
        }
    }
`;

 const Photo = ({ id }) => {
     const [ mutate ] = useMutation(UPLOAD_IMAGE);
    
     function onChange({target: { validity, files: [file] }}) {
         if (validity.valid) {
             mutate({
                 variables: {
                     input: {
                         id,
                         params: {
                             image: file
                         }
                     }
                 }
             });
         }
      }
    
      return (
        <div css={style}>
          <input type="file" required onChange={onChange} />
        </div>
      )
}
```

Note that in order for this to work properly, you need to set the upload connect on the Apollo Client constructor.

```
const CLIENT = new ApolloClient({
  link: new createUploadLink({ ... })
  ...
});
```