# How can one upload an image to a KeystoneJS GraphQL endpoint?

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-client, apollo-server, keystonejs

I'm using TinyMCE in a custom field for the KeystoneJS AdminUI, which is a React app.  I'd like to upload images from the React front to the KeystoneJS GraphQL back.  I can upload the images using a REST endpoint I added to the Keystone server -- passing TinyMCE an `images_upload_handler` callback -- but I'd like to take advantage of Keystone's already-built GraphQL endpoint for an Image list/type I've created.

[image]

I first tried to use the approach detailed in [this article](https://moonhighway.com/how-the-upload-scalar-works), using `axios` to upload the image

```
const getGQL = (theFile) => {
    const query = gql`
  mutation upload($file: Upload!) {
    createImage(file: $file) {
      id
      file {
        path
        filename
      }
    }
  }
`;
// The operation contains the mutation itself as "query"
    // and the variables that are associated with the arguments
    // The file variable is null because we can only pass text
    // in operation variables
    const operation = {
        query,
        variables: {
            file: null
        }
    };
    // This map is used to associate the file saved in the body
    // of the request under "0" with the operation variable "variables.file"
    const map = {
        '0': ['variables.file']
    };

    // This is the body of the request
    // the FormData constructor builds a multipart/form-data request body
    // Here we add the operation, map, and file to upload
    const body = new FormData();
    body.append('operations', JSON.stringify(operation));
    body.append('map', JSON.stringify(map));
    body.append('0', theFile);

    // Create the options of our POST request
    const opts = {
        method: 'post',
        url: 'http://localhost:4545/admin/api',
        body
    };
// @ts-ignore
    return axios(opts);

};
```

but I'm not sure what to pass as `theFile` --  TinyMCE's `images_upload_handler`, from which I need to call the image upload, accepts a `blobInfo` object which contains functions to give me

[image]

The file name doesn't work, neither does the blob -- both give me server errors 500 -- the error message isn't more specific.

I would prefer to use a GraphQL client to upload the image -- [another SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42058634/upload-image-to-graphql-server) suggests using [apollo-upload-client](https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-client).  However, I'm operating within the KeystoneJS environment, and Apollo-upload-client says

> Apollo Client can only have 1 “terminating” Apollo Link that sends the
>   GraphQL requests; if one such as apollo-link-http is already setup,
>   remove it.

I believe Keystone has already set up `Apollo-link-http` (it comes up multiple times on search), so I don't think I can use `Apollo-upload-client`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UploadLink` is just a drop-in replacement for `HttpLink`. There's no reason you shouldn't be able to use it. There's a demo KeystoneJS app [here](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/blob/d89b7bf7da85436c7c3a94543370fa5d377f6b33/demo-projects/blog/app/lib/init-apollo.js) that shows the Apollo Client configuration, including using `createUploadLink`.

Actual usage of the mutation with the `Upload` scalar is shown [here](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/blob/d89b7bf7da85436c7c3a94543370fa5d377f6b33/demo-projects/blog/app/pages/post/new.js).

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/blob/e25ec422bcf3889fc47aa46f0a230666a21b5e22/modules/tinymce/src/core/main/ts/api/file/BlobCache.ts#L31), you should be able to use a custom [image handler](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/handle-async-image-uploads/#imageuploaderoptions) and call `blob` on the provided `blobInfo` object. Something like this:

```
tinymce.init({
  images_upload_handler: async function (blobInfo, success, failure) {
    const image = blobInfo.blob()
    try {
      await apolloClient.mutate(
        gql` mutation($image: Upload!) { ... } `,
        {
          variables: { image }
        } 
      )
      success()
    } catch (e) {
      failure(e)
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I'm a relative newbie with GraphQL -- when you say 'drop-in replacement', what specifically do I do with `UploadLink`?  Their docs say to remove any other 'terminating link' that has been set up.  Do I in fact need to do this? In the context of Keystone, how? -- Also, the example you linked is very helpful, but as I'm operating within a constrained context where I'm only offered things like the file name, the blob, etc (as per above), how do I use this to arrive at the File object that the example is using (which it gets from the form)?

Comment: Normally, you use an HttpLink [like this](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/v3.0-beta/get-started/#create-a-client). Instead of creating an HttpLink, you create the UploadLink as shown [here](https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-client#function-createuploadlink).

Comment: I'll pore through everything.  The one question I have is does any of this change when I'm working within the AdminUI?  That is, looking at the demo  -- https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/blob/d89b7bf7da85436c7c3a94543370fa5d377f6b33/demo-projects/blog/app/lib/init-apollo.js -- it seems to be setting up the Apollo Client from scratch, but within the AdminUI all that's been done already.   Should I do it again, that is, set up my own 'local' Apollo Client?  Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @DanielRearden what about result - blob shouldn't be replaced with new one made with remote url returned from mutation?

Comment: I'm not all that familiar with KeystoneJS, but it looks like the admin app [already uses createUploadLink](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/blob/5c28c1428545527feee1d2a8924511ae80c30ee0/packages/app-admin-ui/client/apolloClient.js)

Answer (score 1):

I used to have the same problem and solved it with Apollo upload link. Now when the app got into the production phase I realized that Apollo client took 1/3rd of the gzipped built files and I created minimal graphql client just for keystone use with automatic image upload. The package is available in npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sylchi/keystone-graphql-client

Usage example that will upload github logo to user profile if there is an user with avatar field set as file:

```
import {  mutate } from  '@sylchi/keystone-graphql-client'

const  getFile  = () =>  fetch('https://github.githubassets.com/images/modules/logos_page/GitHub-Mark.png',
{
    mode:  "cors",
    cache:  "no-cache"
})
.then(response  =>  response.blob())
.then(blob  => {
    return  new  File([blob], "file.png", { type:  "image/png" })
});

getFile().then(file  => {

const  options  = {
    mutation: `
        mutation($id: ID!, $data: UserUpdateInput!){
            updateUser(id: $id, data: $data){
                id
            }
        }
    `,
    variables: {
        id:  "5f5a7f712a64d9db72b30602", //replace with user id
        data: {
            avatar:  file
        }
    }
}

mutate(options).then(result  =>  console.log(result));

});
```

The whole package is just 50loc with 1 dependency :)

Answer (score 1):

The easies way for me was to use `graphql-request`. The advantage is that you don't need to set manually any header prop and it uses the variables you need from the `images_upload_handler` as de [docs](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/image/#images_upload_handler) describe.

I did it this way:

```js
const { request, gql} = require('graphql-request')

const query = gql`
  mutation IMAGE ($file: Upload!) {
    createImage (data:
      file: $file,
    }) {
      id
      file {
        publicUrl
      }
    }
  }
`

images_upload_handler = (blobInfo, success) => {
//                             ^        ^   varibles you get from tinymce
  const variables = {
    file: blobInfo.blob()
  }

  request(GRAPHQL_API_URL, query, variables)
    .then( data => {
      console.log(data)
      success(data.createImage.fileRemote.publicUrl)
    })
}
```

For Keystone 5 editorConfig would stripe out functions, so I clone the field and set the function in the `views/Field.js` file.

Good luck ( ^_^)/*